# RegionPlot Difficulty

Tags: parametric-functions, regions

This code:

```
Plot3D[ArcTan[Tan[y/x]], {x, -1, 2}, {y, -2, 1},
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, 1 <= x^2 + y^2 <= 4 && y <= x]]
```

Give this result:

[image]

This code, however, does a better job on $-\pi/2\le\theta\le0$.

```
ParametricPlot3D[{r Cos[θ], r Sin[θ], 
  ArcTan[Tan[θ]]}, {r, 1, 2}, {θ, -3 Pi/4, Pi/4}, 
 AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}]
```

Gives this result:

[image]

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: the first plot is ok. you should expect high frequency when x around 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to compare the two plots then the second one should be:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{r Cos[θ], r Sin[θ], 
  ArcTan[Tan[Tan[θ]]]}, {r, 1, 2}, {θ, -3 Pi/4, Pi/4}, 
 AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}]
```

[image]

Comment: Absolutely correct. Thanks for the observation and help.

Comment: It was the second plot I wanted, I made a mistake in drawing the first plot. It should have just been ArcTan[y/x]. Now I am learning a bit more, as Limit[ArcTan[Tan[\[Theta]]], \[Theta] -> -Pi/2, Direction -> 1] gives a result $\pi/2$ and Limit[ArcTan[Tan[\[Theta]]], \[Theta] -> -Pi/2, Direction -> -1] gives a result $-\pi/2$. Things are beginning to make more sense.